# Postman response in different order to console log response from request

Tags: reactjs, promise, request, postman, response

When using Postman to test an API a request, the response i get is unordered, which is what I want, i.e.:

```
}
  "23": "Kevin",
  "2": "James",
  "12": "Michael"
}
```

However, when I log the response, it automatically sorts it to:

```
}
  "2": "James",
  "12": "Michael",
  "23": "Kevin"
}
```

I am getting the response in a promise:

```
return this.client.post('/url', data)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('api response: ', response);
```

Is there anyway I can prevent the ordering of the response so I can render the data as desired? I am not sure where, or why the order of the data is different.

Any help will be massively appreciated!

Comment: The order of keys in an object shouldn't matter, if you want to preserve order use Arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot and should not rely on the ordering of elements within a JSON object.

From the JSON specification at http://www.json.org/

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs

As a consequence, JSON libraries are free to rearrange the order of the elements as they see fit. This is not a bug.