# Getting different response from Wordpress API

Tags: json, react-native, wordpress-rest-api

In the browser and Postman i'm getting this response

```
[{"id":2,"count":0,"description":"das","link":"https:\/\/test.meeh.fun\/gij_alpha_taxonomy\/das\/","name":"asd","slug":"das","taxonomy":"gij_alpha_taxonomy","parent":0,"meta":[],"acf":{"image":"https:\/\/test.meeh.fun\/wp-content\/uploads\/2021\/05\/Screen-Shot-2021-05-29-at-10.42.16-PM.png","nsfw":false,"paid_category":false},"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/test.meeh.fun\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/gij_alpha_taxonomy\/2"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/test.meeh.fun\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/gij_alpha_taxonomy"}],"about":[{"href":"https:\/\/test.meeh.fun\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/taxonomies\/gij_alpha_taxonomy"}],"wp:post_type":[{"href":"https:\/\/test.meeh.fun\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/gij_post?gij_alpha_taxonomy=2"}],"curies":[{"name":"wp","href":"https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}","templated":true}]}}]
```

but in ReactNative i'm getting this response

```
[{"_links": {"about": [Array], "collection": [Array], "curies": [Array], "self": [Array], "wp:post_type": [Array]}, "acf": {"image": "https://test.meeh.fun/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/Screen-Shot-2021-05-29-at-10.42.16-PM.png", "nsfw": false, "paid_category": false}, "count": 0, "description": "das", "id": 2, "link": "https://test.meeh.fun/gij_alpha_taxonomy/das/", "meta": [], "name": "asd", "parent": 0, "slug": "das", "taxonomy": "gij_alpha_taxonomy"}]
```

is there any reason i'm getting this different response in react native ?
here is the code

```
let response = await fetch('https://test.meeh.fun/wp-json/wp/v2/gij_alpha_taxonomy', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});

let json = await response.json();

console.log(json)
```

Comment: Try the API with 'User-Agent' in the header.

Comment: @EndLess Same results

Comment: What user-agent you used ?

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36

Comment: @Balalen Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59626805/postman-response-in-different-order-to-console-log-response-from-request